# Silverlight 4 - how can I make text box to have cursor active in it?

Tags: xaml, textbox, silverlight-4.0

I have multiple text boxes on a silverlight page. How can I make one of them active so that I will not have to click it to be able to type into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
    textBox1.Focus();
```

This tries to bring the focus over your textbox.

EDIT:
I assume that you want to select your textbox when the page is loaded. In this situation you nead to bring the focus to the silverlight plug-in first and after that to call Focus() method of your textbox.

Here a way to do this:

```
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
```

Comment: I already tried that. I do textBox1.Focus() and I run the solution, if I start typing nothing happens... so I still have to click on the textbox

Comment: In IE works, but in chrome it doesn't. I think this is because silverlight has a little bit of support problems with chrome. dunno.
Anyway I'm marking your answer as the solution.

Thank you!